# Get notified on a segue when a view controller is dismissed from navigation item native button

Tags: ios, storyboard

Let's say I am pushing view controller B from view controller A.
Since I am using the native "back button" that iOS creates I don't have a reference to the back button in the story board.

All I need is to know when view controller B is about to dismiss it self back to view controller A. (I can not count on viewWillDisappear).

Any Idea ?
Thanks

Comment: Why can't you count on viewWillDisappear?

Comment: because view will disappear will get called even when controller B pushes controller C. And I need to know that he is being dismissed. Thanks.

Comment: I am asking because I had the very same case to what you have, I manged it by setting a flag for pop, push or modal in viewWillDisappear. ;)